# SQL Server function return different select statement based on the parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, function

I need a function that returns different select statements based on the value of the parameter. I wrote it like below but it throws an error like

> A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this
>   context.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Sample] (@SampleValue int)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
BEGIN
IF @SampleValue=100
RETURN(
 SELECT ....
)
ELSE
RETURN(
 SELECT ....

)
```

Comment: Why not return the values from the select? Alternatively, you can return a string that represents the query.

Comment: Do the two select statements produce result sets with the same "shape"? (Number of columns, for each column, same name and type)

Comment: Yes they are same. Only difference is one of them has a WHERE statement for filtering.

Comment: My purpose in here is if the parameter comes with a specific value I need to return a select statement without WHERE statement and if the parameter's value is different than this specific value, I need to filter the select statement with this parameter.

Comment: @user1288423 - If you want to do a different filter based on the parameter, it might be simple for you to explain the logic and do it in just one query. If doing two queries is ok, then you can see my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per your comments - just write it as a single query - there's no need to write it out twice.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Sample] (@SampleValue int)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
BEGIN
RETURN(
 SELECT .... WHERE @SampleValue = 100 OR (<rest of where clause from other branch>)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it worked. It's a pratical solution to my problem I don't how I couldn't think this =)